# how to solve it by residue theorem

Tags: complex-integration

i have to solve the folowing integral by using contour integration & residue theorem
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^2+2x+2}\ dx$$
i factorised $x^2+2x+2=(x+1+i)(x+1-i)$ where $x=-1+i$ & $x=-1-i$ are single poles 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{(x+1+i)(x+1-i)}\ dx$$
i got stuck here, don't know which contour is to to be used? please help me solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int \limits^{\infty }_{-\infty }\frac{\sin \left( x\right) }{x^{2}+2x+2} dx=\Im \left[ \int \limits^{\infty }_{-\infty }\frac{e^{iz}}{z^{2}+2z+2} dz\right] =\Im \left[ 2\pi i \sum Res\left( f\left( z\right) , z_{0}\right) \right] $$
you have one pole inside your contour  $ z=i-1$ so your  Residue will be $$2\pi i\lim \limits_{z\to i-1}\left( z+1-i\right) \frac{e^{iz}}{\left( z+1-i\right) \left( z+i+1\right) } =\Im \left( 2\pi i \left( \frac{e^{i\left( i-1\right) }}{2i} \right) \right) =\Im\left( \frac{\pi \left( \cos \left( 1\right) -i \sin \left( 1\right) \right) }{e}\right) $$
So the integral equal to $$ \int \limits^{\infty }_{-\infty }\frac{\sin \left( x\right) }{x^{2}+2x+2} dx=\boxed{\frac{-\pi \sin \left( 1\right) }{e}} $$

Comment: nice answer  ................+1

Comment: please tell me how you knew the pole $i-1$ is inside contour?

Comment: in the function $ R(z) e^{imz} $ . Let $ \sum Res(f(z), z_{0}) $  be the sum of the residues of $R(z)e^{imz} $ in the upper half plane.  So that $ z=-i-1$ not in your contour.

Comment: why did you consider only upper half plane?

Comment: You can use the lower half plane. but in this case your function will be  $$\Im \left[ \int \limits^{\infty }_{-\infty }\frac{e^{-iz}}{z^{2}+2z+2} dz\right] $$ and you will take the second pole $ z=-1-i $ read this (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530204/why-do-we-use-only-upper-half-plane-to-do-residue-integration)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45237/discussion-between-refaat-m-sayed-and-bhaskara-iii).